# can i create a UIViewController comprised of UITableView and mixing with other UIKits

Tags: cocoa-touch

please patient with my poor english.

I'd bad concept of *UIView, UIViewController, UITableView, UITableViewController*..

Now I'd created a NavigationController and **ViewController with SegmentedControl** and I don't know how to add a custom TableView in the ViewController. All the examples I've seen are subclassing a **UITableViewController** as it is a whole table without other control in between.

Can anyone show me some guideline to get to create a Form's like apps?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own answer.

UITableView has two properties call headerView and footerView
these two view are able to put in any custom view to display your custom component on the top and foot of the table.